# UIScrollView Tapping Buttons Not Working

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

I have a game that I am currently creating, and in my shop I wanted to use a scrolling view like the game Color Switch. However, when I tap on the button they will not run because the scroll view doesn't work like that. Can anyone help me fix this?

I followed this tutorial to make the scroll view & have the helper in my project: https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-SpriteKit-UIScrollView-Helper

Here's my Custom Scroll View:

```
 /// Scroll direction
 enum ScrollDirection: Int {
case Vertical
case Horizontal
 }

 /// Custom UIScrollView class
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

// MARK: - Static Properties

/// Touches allowed
static var disabledTouches = false

/// Scroll view
private static var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// MARK: - Properties

/// Nodes touched. This will forward touches to node subclasses.
private var nodesTouched: [AnyObject] = []

/// Current scene
private let currentScene: SKScene

/// Moveable node
private let moveableNode: SKNode

/// Scroll direction
private var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection

// MARK: - Deinit
  deinit {
    print("Custom scroll view deinit")
  }

 // MARK: - Init
init(frame: CGRect, scene: SKScene, moveableNode: SKNode, scrollDirection: ScrollDirection) {
    self.currentScene = scene
    self.moveableNode = moveableNode
    self.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
    super.init(frame: frame)

    CustomScrollView.scrollView = self
    self.frame = frame
    indicatorStyle = .White
    scrollEnabled = true
    //self.minimumZoomScale = 1
    //self.maximumZoomScale = 3
    canCancelContentTouches = false
    userInteractionEnabled = true
    delegate = self

    clipsToBounds = true

    //contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)

    // Flip for spritekit (only needed for horizontal)
    if self.scrollDirection == .Horizontal {
        let flip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,-1)
        self.transform = flip
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
   }

  // MARK: - Touches
  extension CustomScrollView {

/// Began
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(currentScene)

        guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }

        /// Call touches began in current scene
        currentScene.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

        /// Call touches began in all touched nodes in the current scene
        nodesTouched = currentScene.nodesAtPoint(location)
        for node in nodesTouched {
            node.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)



        }
    }
   }

/// Moved
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(currentScene)

        guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }

        /// Call touches moved in current scene
        currentScene.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

        /// Call touches moved in all touched nodes in the current scene
        nodesTouched = currentScene.nodesAtPoint(location)
        for node in nodesTouched {
            node.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}

/// Ended
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(currentScene)

        guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }

        /// Call touches ended in current scene
        currentScene.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)













        /// Call touches ended in all touched nodes in the current scene
        nodesTouched = currentScene.nodesAtPoint(location)
        for node in nodesTouched {
            node.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)





        }
    }
}

/// Cancelled
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)

    for touch in touches! {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(currentScene)

        guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }

        /// Call touches cancelled in current scene
        currentScene.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)

        /// Call touches cancelled in all touched nodes in the current scene
        nodesTouched = currentScene.nodesAtPoint(location)
        for node in nodesTouched {
            node.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}
  }

 // MARK: - Touch Controls
  extension CustomScrollView {

/// Disable
class func disable() {
    CustomScrollView.scrollView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
    CustomScrollView.disabledTouches = true
}

/// Enable
class func enable() {
    CustomScrollView.scrollView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    CustomScrollView.disabledTouches = false
}
 }

  // MARK: - Delegates
  extension CustomScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollDirection == .Horizontal {
        moveableNode.position.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    } else {
        moveableNode.position.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
}
  }
```

Here's my moveableScrollNode, Button Node I created & touch function:

```
let moveableNode = SKNode()
 weak var scrollView: CustomScrollView!










override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    addChild(moveableNode)




    scrollView = CustomScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height), scene: self, moveableNode: moveableNode, scrollDirection: .Vertical)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height * 3)// makes it 3 times the height
    moveableNode.zPosition = 0
    view.addSubview(scrollView)





    let page1ScrollView = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height))
    page1ScrollView.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    moveableNode.addChild(page1ScrollView)

    let page2ScrollView = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height))
    page2ScrollView.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - (self.frame.size.height))
    moveableNode.addChild(page2ScrollView)

    let page3ScrollView = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height))
    page3ScrollView.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - (self.frame.size.height * 2))
    moveableNode.addChild(page3ScrollView)








let sprite1Page1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Buy5Button")
     sprite1Page1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * -0.4, self.frame.size.height*0.05)
         page1ScrollView.addChild(sprite1Page1)
 }

 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if sprite1Page1.containsPoint(location) {

            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

                let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 1)

                let newScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                newScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
                self.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's NOT a UIButton, it's a node button that I created myself.

Comment: Tip: you can [edit] your question to change/add information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `UIScrollView` with `UIButtons`

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene,UIScrollViewDelegate {


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */


        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 4, self.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true


        let button = UIButton(type: .System)

        button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 300, 40)
        button.setTitle("Something", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "something", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)

        self.view?.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    func something() {
        print("OK")
    }
}
```